# How to write data into a specific range based on a variable

Tags: google-apps-script

In the image below, Table 1 is an editable table where a user can change the values. Table 2 is a master table that I want to update with the changed values from Table 1. The unique identifier for each table is the Full Name (Column A). In this example, I'd like to:

1. Get the data from Table 1 associated with the Full Name entered into B1 (Washington, George).
2. Update the right record in Table 2 (row 13) with the values from Table 1.

[Table 1 and Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7AO8.png)

I know that I can use getvalues() and setvalues() to get the data from Table 1 and write it into Table 2. I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the right range (row 6 in Table 1 for the getvalues() function and row 13 in Table 2 for the setvalues() function) based on the value in B1 (Washington, George).

If I were using Excel VBA, I'd do a search in Table 1 and Table 2 for the value in B1 and then select the entire row. I've read articles about how to get a range based on A1 notation, user selection, and column/row identification, but I can't find anything related to getting a range relative to the location of a specific value in the data set.

Comment: take a look at textFinder

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Your question does not seem defined well enough to give a definite answer. For starters, Apps Script runs on Google's servers rather than your computer, so there is no direct access to the clipboard. Please visit the links below to learn a bit of Apps Script and edit your question to show your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to read the data in the sheet:

```
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
```

Follow with this to find the row index of `searchValue`:

```
const keys = data.map(row => row[0]);
const rowIndex = keys.indexOf(searchValue);
```

To write a `values` array in the row, use this:

```
sheet
  .getRange(rowIndex, 1)
  .offset(0, 0, 1, values.length)
  .setValues(values);
```

Some of the best resources for learning Google Apps Script include the [Beginner's Guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-beginner-guide/), the [New Apps Script Editor guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-ide/), the [Fundamentals of Apps Script with Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-1) codelab, the [Extending Google Sheets page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets), [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/), [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).

Comment: Thank you for this! I'll try this out and look at those resources, as well.